# How to display HTML Ohm special character in TCPDF?

Tags: tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to generate PDFs from HTML code and I can't get certain HTML special characters to render properly. Here's my barebones code:

```
require_once('../libraries/tcpdf_6_0_020/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'LETTER', true, 'UTF-8', false);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

$output = 'this is a special character: &#8486;';

//echo $output;die();

$pdf->writeHTML($output, true, false, false, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('generated pdf.pdf', 'I');
```

The output of the above is:

```
this is a special character: ?
```

There are a number of questions on here on this same subject and most of them say to change the constructor to the following:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
```

I tried that, but then the output becomes:

```
this is a special character: &#8486;
```

What should I do to make HTML special characters render properly?

Comment: Use `$pdf->setFont(...)` to set a Unicode font.

Comment: @JoopEggen I added `$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20, '', 'false');` below the TCPDF constructor, but it still displays the question mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();

$html = "this is a special character: &#8486;";

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$pdf->lastPage();

$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: I tried `$output = $pdf->unhtmlentities('this is a special character: &#8486;');`, but unfortunately it still outputs a `?`.

Comment: I got the euro character code (8364) from this page: http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps, and it renders correctly in my example. So it's almost as if TCPDF doesn't know how to render certain symbols such as the Ohm symbol?

Comment: Thanks, but aren't you just echoing the html out to the page instead of generating a PDF? If echo out the HTML to the page, the Ohm symbol displays fine, but when I output it as a PDF then it displays the question mark.

Comment: @Nate I updated the code to create the pdf. Your problem is in the SetFont I think

Comment: It works, thank you! So why does the font you used work, but the default font (and helvetica, which is what I used in my real code) doesn't work?

Comment: @Nate "Deja Vu Sans Mono is part of the Deja Vu family of fonts and is one of the most complete Unicode fonts available. This means you have access to a wide range of special symbols including mathematical symbols like arrows, operators and special alphabets." ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was

```
html_entity_decode(utf8_encode('my string'));
```